# typescript init Object from extended type

Tags: typescript

I get a IPerson from the database.

How can I write the IPerson in an ILastLogin and additional set LOGIN Date?

```
export interface IPerson {
    PERSONID: number
    NAME: string
}

export interface ILastLogin extends IPerson{
    LOGIN: Date
}


fetchPersonFromDB(params)
     .then(data => {

        if (data && (data.data as IPerson[]) && (data.data.length > 0)) {
                  
            const person = data.data[0] as IPerson;

             //It doesn't work like that.                     
            const lastLogin:ILastPerson = {person, LOGIN:new Date()};  
          }
        })
```

Comment: `{...person, LOGIN:new Date()}`

Comment: perfect, that's how it works thank you.